# The Laplacian and a nice PDE

Tags: multivariable-calculus, harmonic-functions

Given the Laplacian:

$$\Delta u= \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
$$

I had to show that by using this   $$v(r,\theta ):=u(r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta )
$$

I can get this:

$$\Delta u = \left ( \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial \theta ^2} \right )
$$

After many hours of painful algebra manipulation I did it. Now they are asking me to solve the following differential partial equation:

$$\Delta u=x(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}
$$
So I am 100% that I have to use the first part of the problem or life wouldn't make sense for me. So I did it:

$$\left ( \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial \theta ^2} \right )=x(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}
$$

I also know that $$x^{2}+y^{2}=r^{2}
$$ so I get:
$$\left ( \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial \theta ^2} \right )=r\cos \theta (r^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}=r^{4}\cos \theta
$$
And after that I don't know what to do.
I have to find a solution in the following form:
$$v(r,\theta )=X(r)T(\theta )
$$
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left ( \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial \theta ^2} \right )=r^{4}\cos \theta \text{     (1)}$$

Setting $v(r,\theta )=X(r)\cos\theta $ in (1) above, we obtain an non-homogeneous second order ODE for $X(r)$:

$$X^{''}(r)+\frac{1}{r} X^{'}(r)-\frac{1}{r^2} X(r)=r^4$$

You can use the standard technique to solve it. The solution is given by:

$$X(r)=c_1\frac{r^2+1}{2r}+c_2\frac{r^2-1}{2r}+\frac{r^6}{35}$$

Comment: amazing! once you got the ODE did you use undetermined coeff or variation of parameters? just for curiosity

Comment: I used Mathematica. If you do not use Mathematica, you may set $X(r)=Y(r)/r^{1/2}$, then you will end up solving $r^2 Y''(r)-\frac{3}{4}Y(r)=r^{13/2}$. The homogeneous part of the solution is now $Y(r)=b_1 r^{3/2}+b_2 r^{-1/2}$.